# XSL Style Sheets itemstyle.xsl

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, microsoft-access

I have dynamic image slide show in website sp2010 .  the first picture is hyperlink to other website. 
I found  for image in  itemstyle.xsl Can I remove  (hyperlink for image ) from itemstyle.xsl from site >> View All Site Content > Style Library > XSL Style Sheets > Style Library by download copy of itemstyle.xsl and edit from notepad then upload it . Can I? What's the steps?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create a copy of the Itemstyle.xsl and edit it to suit your needs. After that, upload and publish it (!!).

You will also need to refer to the customized CopyOfItemStyle.xsl (or whatever you call it) in the CQWP. There are two ways to do this:

1. export the CQWP from the browser and edit the exported "*.webpart" file, then import the edited CQWP into the final page.
2. edit the CQWP in SharePoint Designer and set the property in the Properties pane.

You need to point the ItemXslLink property to the location of the custom item style file.

If you edit the .webpart file, change the entry to look along the lines of the following

```
<property name="ItemXslLink" type="string">/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/MyCustomItemStyle.xsl</property>
```

If you use SPD, just enter the path in the value of the property.